# Get tabControl1.SelectedIndex from another class

Tags: c#, winforms, class, tabcontrol

I'm a beginner in C# and I always have some issues to get properties from an object defined in a class into a different class. Maybe there's a part of C# that I didn't learn. I work with an existing project made by a previous developper.

I simplify, I have two class : one with all my objects and events :

```
public partial class MainWindow : Form
    {
      [...]  //code
    }
```

And an other class handling communication (bluetooth) with a device:

```
public class GCOM
    {
       [...]  //code
    }
```

In my MainWindow class, I have a tabControl object with two tabPages.
In my GCOM class, I want to get the property of the tabControl tabControl1.SelectedIndex, but it's not recognized in the actual context.

```
public class GCOM
        {
               if (tabControl1.SelectedIndex == 1)
               {
                  [...]  //code
               }
        }
```

What should I do ?

Thanks !

Comment: Your `GCOM` class really doesn't want to know anything about your Form (it handles data exchange, not UI elements). When you want to notify that you have new data or *something* has changed in your class, rise an event and pass the *news* in a custom class derived from EventArgs, add the public properties needed and set their values to what the consumers of this class need to know. The subscriber of this event will be notified that *something happend* or *something changed* and use the public properties values to update what needs to be updated. Maybe enforce the contract using an Interface.

Comment: Hi Jimi and thanks for the answer. I'll try like this but it seems a bit hard for my level. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok thanks everyone, I used the invoke method like this and it's working:

Main form:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Form
{
    public int getSelectedTabIndex()
    {
        if (tabControl1.InvokeRequired)
            return (int)tabControl1.Invoke(new Func<int>(getSelectedTabIndex));
        else
            return tabControl1.SelectedIndex;
    }
}
```

Second form :

```
public class GCOM
{
    if (MainWindow.GetInstance().getSelectedTabIndex() == 1)
    {
        // code
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First make sure tabControl1 is public in `Form.Designer.cs`. Than at GCOM class get instance of Form and you can access tabControl1 by `form.tabControl1`

**EDIT:**
If you only need to know which tab is selected and no other operations, just create appropriate method at Form:

```
public int getSelectedTabIndex{
   return tabContol1.SelectedIndex;
}
```

Comment: Ok I have set tabControl1 to public but stupid question, how to get instance of Form ? if (MainWindow.GetInstance().tabControl1.SelectedIndex == 0) get me an exception System.InvalidOperationException

Comment: From where you create it (e.g. at Program.cs if it is your main from) pass it as argument to the GCOM. Or you can create method at Form that returns itself like `Form getInstance() { return this }` or  it can return just tabControl1 `TabControl getTabContol() { return this.tabControl1 }`